# company-mode popups and magit current region are dark while current theme is light

Tags: magit, company-mode, themes, colors, popup

I've been successfully using `lsp-mode` and `magit` for a while with a **light theme** (leuven).

Today I was messing with something seemingly unrelated (`company-mode` and `auto-complete` settings in my `~/.emacs` file) and all of a sudden popups in `lsp-mode` + `company-mode` appear as if in a dark theme:
[image]

The same goes now in `magit` for the area where the cursor is:
[image]

Needless to say, it's all unreadable now!

How can I get the light colours back?

My `~/.emacs` contents are here, if it helps: https://pastebin.com/Hph4VXvH

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was this from my `~/.emacs` file:

```
'(frame-background-mode 'dark)
'(hl-sexp-background-color "#1c1f26")
```

I'm not really sure how it got there, but setting `frame-background-mode` to nil (so that it will be set according to theme) and commenting the second line did the trick:

```
 '(frame-background-mode 'nil)
 ;; '(hl-sexp-background-color "#1c1f26")
```